mirror modifier is not working properly

i am trying to mirror the object to fit into the corners of the chest but i an getting a strange mirrors, it worked perfectly before on the same object but not anymore even though i applied all transforms it still gives me same result .

You are using the chest as mirror object. Are you sure that the chest is perfectly symmetrical and its origin is at the center of this symmetry? This is unfortunately not visible in your screenshot

If you applied the rotation of the chest, then that's messing it up.
